# Iterate over huge list in Python and get results faster

Tags: python-3.x

In python 3 we are iterating over JSON and construing a different JSON, a sample like

```
for i in range (len(json1)):
    final.append({"id":json1[i]['id'],"name":json1[i]['migrated_data']['name'],"date":customfunc(json1[i]['migrated_data']['name'])})
```

but its sequential and time consuming, is there a faster way to iterate and get the final result. There are more than 100K records in json1

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it into a list comprehension, and iterate over `json1` directly:

```
final = [{"id": j['id'], "name": j['migrated_data']['name']} for j in json1]
```

That should be somewhat faster then a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different way could be to *skip* the loading of the original JSON file entirely.

You could use `mmap` to map the original JSON file into memory and then use regular expressions to fish out only the data that you need.

Comment: thanks for the response, the data for the final json is derived though a different function for few keys (like the "date" in above example), i have apporx 25 keys & 100K elements in the json, iterating in batch / parallel processing could help retrieve faster i guess, I need to process in parallel and join the results in the end. Let me explore more on the mmap will help and get back to you.